# Torsion-free and projective modules over a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, dedekind-domain

Suppose that $A$ is a Dedekind domain (and integral domain). I am trying to prove that if $M$ is a torsion-free $A$-module, then it is projective and vice versa.

Suppose that $M$ is projective. Then it is well-known that $M$ is a direct summand of a free module and hence it is a submodule of free module $F$. Now suppose $a \in A$ such that $a \neq 0$ and $m \in M$. Since $F$ is free, we can write $m = a_1 f_1 + ... + a_k f_k$. Suppose $am = 0$, so $a a_1 f_1 +...+aa_k f_k = 0$, and $a a_i = 0$, and we have $a_i = 0$, since $A$ is an integral domain. It follows that $m = 0$ and this is a contradiction, so $M$ is torsion-free.

I was trying to prove then that "torsion-free $\Rightarrow$ projective" by using a similar argument, however I got stuck. Could you please suggest, how to prove the other direction?

Comment: Have you tried using the condition that a module is projective if and only if every surjection onto it can be split?

Comment: @KevinCarlson I showed that if $M$ is projective, then for any surjective homomorphism $\varphi : K \rightarrow M$, there exists a homomorphism $\psi : M \rightarrow K$ such that $\varphi \circ \psi = id_M$ (well, it is easy), but I do not know, how to apply this here.

Answer (score 3):

Finitely generated and torsion-free implies projective, but infinitely generated torsion-free modules need not be projective.  (E.g. the fraction field of $A$ is not projective as an $A$-module; think about $\mathbb Q$ over $\mathbb Z$.)

This is why you are having trouble proving it; you have to use finitely generated
in the argument. (More generally, over any commutative ring with $1$, f.p. and flat is equivalent to f.g. and projective.)

Comment: Yes, I have just discovered this, so $M$ must be finitely generated. Now I am trying to use this fact and also the fact suggested by @KevinCarlson. So I start like this: let $m \in M$ and $m$ is non-zero. Now $m = a_1 m_1 + ... + a_k m_k$ and $am \neq 0$. But I still do not know how to apply the fact that every surjective homomorphism splits.

Comment: @MichaelRichards: Dear Michael, Do you know about localization and/or flatness and/or projective dimension.  This question becomes easier to solve if some of these concepts are invoked.  Regards,

Comment: Well, I know the concept of localization.